# How to keep the same image orientation of the image being saved to the server using jQuery or PHP whichever is appropriate?

Tags: php, jquery, orientation, screen-orientation, exif

I'm using **PHP 5.5.18, jQuery, AJAX, HTML5, Bootstrap framework(v.3.3.0)** for my website.

My website is mainly intended for smartphones' and smart devices' users. So it should work fine on mobile browsers as well as PC/laptop browsers.

In one of my forms I'm providing a facility to the user to either capture image from device camera or choose the existing image on device's image gallery. After this the same image should upload to the server.

Now everything is working absolutely fine and perfect. The only issue persisting there is change in image orientation.

Let me focus on the issue I'm facing. If user takes a photograph using the device camera in "Landscape orientation" the orientation of the same image is changed to "Portrait" if I look at the image saved on server. Same is the thing happening if user captures the photograph in "Portrait orientation", it changes to "Landscape" on server image.

I googled a lot for this solution then I come to know about **"Imagick PHP extension"**. But as this extension is not activated by default I can't enable it on the server **since I've no privilege to do it**. So I'm asking for some other solution using jQuery or PHP whichever is beneficial in this situation.

Following is my code for your reference:

**HTML Code:**

```
<form id="request_form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="file" name="student_image" id="student_image" accept="image/*" capture/>
</form>
```

**jQuery-AJAX Code:**

```
$('#request_form').submit(function(e) {

  var form = $(this);

  var formdata = false;

  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    url         : 'request.php',
    type        : 'POST',    
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success: function(response) {

      var responseObject = $.parseJSON(response);    
      if(responseObject.error_message) {

        if ($(".alert-dismissible")[0]) {
          $('.alert-dismissible').remove();   
        }  
        alert(responseObject.error_message);    

      } else {
        alert("Success");       
      }
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["student_image"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["student_image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
      $error_msg = "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
      $uploadOk = 1;

    } else {
      $error_msg = "File is not an image.";
      $uploadOk = 0;      
    }
  }

  // Allow certain file formats
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $error_msg = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["student_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      $success = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["student_image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      $error_msg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }

  if($error_msg != ''){
    $data = array();
    $data['error_message'] = $error_msg;
    $data = json_encode($data);     
    echo $data;
    die;
  } else {
    $data = array();
    $data['success_message'] = $success;
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
    die;   
  }
?>
```

I've got following function which could do the job for me but I'm not understanding how to give call to this function and how to get the image from it which is to be saved to the server. Please help me in it.

```
<?php
function image_fix_orientation(&$image, $filename) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);

    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;

            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                break;

            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

If you need any further information regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be the rotation of the device is stored in the EXIF data? Check the following link for some information: http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html PHP itself can handle EXIF data if a module is installed. Read up upon it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: As we talked about on the chat. There is no effort made or any visible tries to solve this problem. As I told you, you can solve this with javascript. So please start trying to solve it, if you get stuck, please edit the question. So far this question is unfit as it is literally just asking for code and not fit for the site. As there is no code trying to solve the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not bother to directly use the image functions of PHP, but rather rely on an existing (abstraction) library.

Imagine, which has three drivers already provided: GD, Imagick and Gmagick.
https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

After including the library in your project, use it like this to save an image rotated correctly, from camera. It will require the exif extension to be installed.

```
    $imagefile = $_FILES["..."]["tmp_name"];
    if(class_exists('Gmagick'))
    {
        $imagine = new \Imagine\Gmagick\Imagine();
    }
    elseif(class_exists('Imagick'))
    {
        $imagine = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
    }
    else
    {
        $imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
    }

    $image = $imagine->open($imagefile);

    $filterAutorotate = new \Imagine\Filter\Basic\Autorotate();
    $filterAutorotate->apply($image);

    $filename = 'brand new .jpg';
    $image->save($filename/*, array() $options/*);
```

Reading metadata for doing it manually, see here https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/blob/develop/lib/Imagine/Image/Metadata/ExifMetadataReader.php